# Finding Members between a Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, teradata

I need to find Membership between two dates ( 7-01-14 and 6-30-15) who have been members at least 4 months or more during that time frame.There is a START_DATE and an END_DATE column. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can you show us all your columns?

Comment: Please, show what have you tried and some samples of data and output will be very useful!

Comment: Here's an advice - read [ask]. Edit your question to include the relevant tables ddl and some sample data as ddl. Also, include desired results.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for sqlserver 2012. If you are using an earlier version, you can replace the where clause:

```
DECLARE @t table(START_DATE date, END_DATE date)
INSERT @t values
('2015-01-01','2015-08-30'),('2015-01-01','2015-12-30'),
('2015-08-01','2015-12-30'),('2015-11-01','2017-12-30'),
('2016-01-01','2017-12-30'),('2017-01-01','2017-12-30')

DECLARE @from date='2015-7-01'
DECLARE @to   date='2016-03-01'

SELECT *
FROM @t
WHERE
  DATEADD(month,4, IIF(@from<START_DATE, START_DATE, @FROM)) <=
  IIF(@to>END_DATE, END_DATE, @to)

/*
  --this is for sqlserver 2008
  DATEADD(month,4, CASE WHEN @from<START_DATE THEN START_DATE ELSE @FROM END) <=
  CASE WHEN @to>END_DATE THEN END_DATE ELSE @to END
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
select * 
from YourTable 
where DateColumn between '2014/01/7' and '2006/05/30' and 
    start_date >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -4, current_timestamp)), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets call your table Enrollment.

First.. we want all people who were enrolled between `7-01-14` and `6-30-15`

```
Select * 
From Enrollment 
Where Start_Date Between '7-01-14' and '6-30-15'
And End_Date Between '7-01-14' and '6-30-15'
```

Also, the membership has to be at least found months long in that timespan.

```
Select * 
From Enrollment 
Where Start_Date Between '7-01-14' and '6-30-15'
And End_Date Between '7-01-14' and '6-30-15'
And DateDiff (month, Start_Date, End_Date) > 4
```

But consider these scenarios:

- What happens if somebody signs up on '6-25-15' (5 days before end cutoff) and is active for 4 months?
- What happens if somebody signs up on '4-01-14' (3 months before beginning cutoff) and is active for 4 months?

You will have to make appropriate changes to the query in that case to take care of these scenarios if you need them.

For example, if the Start_Date OR End_Date can be between the cutoff dates specified, but the membership still needs to be 4 months long

```
Select * 
From Enrollment 
Where 
(
    Start_Date Between '7-01-14' and '6-30-15'
    OR End_Date Between '7-01-14' and '6-30-15'
)
And DateDiff (month, Start_Date, End_Date) >= 4
```

But what if the Start_Date is smaller than beginning of the cutff, and the End_Date is larger than the end of cutoff, and the membership still needs to be 4 months long

```
Select * 
From Enrollment 
Where 
(
    (Start_Date Between '7-01-14' and '6-30-15' OR End_Date Between '7-01-14' and '6-30-15')
    OR
    (Start_Date < '7-01-14' and End_Date > '6-30-15')
)
And DateDiff (month, Start_Date, End_Date) >= 4
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work for 2 reasons, datediff in month can be 3 months and 1 day and still be included. Another reason is that you are missing people with start_date and end_date outside the interval

Comment: you are not checking how long time people have been member in the interval, basically 1 day of membership would be acceptable in your calculation, if people were members before and after the interval, they are  not considered